# How to update table ssn values to have dashes?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table called test. there are several records that have unformatted SSNs (i.e. they are missing the dashes)

They are:

```
123456789
```

When I want them to be formatted like:

```
123-45-6789
```

I want to run a script that can insert in these 2 dashes for records like this that are strings with 9 characters.

Comment: Formatting data is really the job of the front end; if you amend the data, what happens when new data that's also unformatted is inserted?

Comment: how did they get into the system that way?  Do you have a way to define only those needing to be updated like where the length of it is 9?  are you sure you'll only be updating ones with missing dashes that way?  the update is straight forward you're just setting the value to `substring(ssn,1,3)+'-'+substring(ssn,4,2)+...`  or use concat.()... be sure to write it as a select before an update and verify what's changing.  AND make sure you have where clasues when updating and validating transaction counts before committing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the rows you can use the following `insert()` string syntax to check its functionality:

```
with test as (
  select '123456789' as ssn
)
select insert(insert(ssn,4,0,'-'),7,0,'-')
from test;

update test set ssn=insert(insert(ssn,4,0,'-'),7,0,'-')
where ssn not like '%-%';
```

It might be a better idea to leave the data as-is and add a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) that implements the above insert syntax instead. This depends on the data, which you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses the regexp functions

> ```
> update test 
> set SSN = regexp_replace(SSN, '([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})$','\\1-\\2-\\3')
> where SSN RLIKE '^[0-9]{9}$'
> ```

> ```
> select * from test
> ```
>
> ```
> | SSN         |
> | :---------- |
> | 123-45-6789 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=00f87f6c42483f478cab5d7500644591)*